# Web App, Android Vs Iphone Scroll

Tags: php, javascript, android, iphone, web-applications

I am creating a web app that I want to work on iPhones and Androids.

So far it works perfectly on iPhone, but on Android, it will only scroll down the page if it is zoomed in a little.  The problem is, I don't want to allow users to zoom.

Also, this is weird, it works on some droids but not others.  On one of my friends phones, it works (but zooms even though I tell it not to) and on others it does not zoom and also does on scroll.

The only thing that seems to work is to take the whole meta tag (<)meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/(>) away, but then that makes it look bad on both android and iphone.

```
<head> <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/> <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /> <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" /> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="isicon.png"/> <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="isbackground.png" /> <link rel="stylesheet" href="is.css" type="text/css" media="screen, mobile" title="main" charset="utf-8"> <title>Title</title> </head>
```

Comment: my app can scroll down on iphone, but on some android phones, it won't scroll down.

Comment: What is the technology you are using ? jQuery Mobile ?

Comment: Since I don't know what that is, I'm gunna say no....  My app is an html website that uses php and javascript.  The thing that seems to be the problem is the meta tag in the <head> tag of the page.  When I totally delete the tag above, it works fine, but I don't want to do that because it makes the app look bad.

Comment: Well then one quick and simple solution is to use selective imports based on the user agent. If android then do this or do anything else.

Comment: <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="isicon.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="isbackground.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="is.css" type="text/css" media="screen, mobile" title="main" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

Comment: I was really trying to avoid using different code for different user agents, but if I have to i will

Answer (score 0):

It was the `overflow: hidden;` in my css file causing the problem